# Deleting item with jdbc from table with relations

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, crud, one-to-many

im writing application using jdbc and not using JPA methods. Somehow i cannot find sources and a way how to operate with relations. In this case i want to delete item in one table which has one-many relationship with other table, like this

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    id         BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email      VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    password   VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    enabled    BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    non_locked BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    image_url  VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/149/149071.png',
    CONSTRAINT UQ_Users_Email UNIQUE (email)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Give;

CREATE TABLE Give (
                      id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                      type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                      amount DOUBLE NOT NULL,
                      amount_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
                      description VARCHAR(500),
                      img_url  VARCHAR(255),
                      location VARCHAR(500),
                      status VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                      users_give_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                      FOREIGN KEY (users_give_id) REFERENCES Users(id),
                      CONSTRAINT FK_Give_Users FOREIGN KEY (users_give_id) REFERENCES Users(id)
);
```

now in repository implementation im executing the deletion

```
@Override
    public Give deleteGive(Long id, Long userId) {
        try {
Give giveToDelete = get(id);
            String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM Give WHERE id = ? AND users_give_id = ?";
            int rowsAffected = jdbc.getJdbcTemplate().update(deleteQuery, id, userId);
            if (rowsAffected == 0) {
                throw new ApiException("No Give found by id: " + id);
            }
            return giveToDelete;
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException exception) {
            throw new ApiException("No Give found by id: " + id);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error(exception.getMessage());
            throw new ApiException("An error occurred. Please try again.");
        }
    }
```

i suspect that the way i handle users_give_id is not right, since its relation id, which also then needs to be deleted. Maybe someone is more familiar with jdbc and can explain the right approach to delete item and relation as well, otherwise, executing this i get error ": No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'users_give_id': No value registered for key 'users_give_id'". Would really appreciate even suggestion or some similar example with deletion, i can work on it.

For reference my controller method

```
    @DeleteMapping("/give/delete/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpResponse> deleteGive(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDTO user, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        Long userId = user.getId();
        Give deletedGive = giveService.deleteGive(id, userId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(
                HttpResponse.builder()
                        .timeStamp(now().toString())
                        .data(of("give", deletedGive))
                        .message("Give deleted")
                        .status(OK)
                        .statusCode(OK.value())
                        .build());
    }
```

Comment: Can you debug and see what is the value of the useId. Your `DELETE` statement and its usage looks correct to me and I suspect (without checking the behaviour myself) `userId` is null. The foreigner key relationship here has nothing to do with deletion. It would be the other way around; not allowing you to delete an `user` for as long there are `give` associated to it. Also the fact that you make two database trips one to retrieve the `giveToDelete` and one to actually delete is not not performant. I suggest you look into using `DELETE ....RETURNING` syntax.

Comment: Also in the `Give` table definition you don't need to specify `FOREIGN KEY` twice. Just the `CONSTRAINT FK_Give_Users FOREIGN KEY` will suffice for most (if not all) database engines.

Comment: Thank you for input, so i can try to change things. I took out the  CONSTRAINT FK_Give_Users FOREIGN KEY (users_give_id) REFERENCES Users(id) and so far looks nothing is broken. I also took out @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDTO user to work only with id, and changed query to   String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM harvest.Give WHERE id = ?"; and still get  error  No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'users_give_id': No value registered for key 'users_give_id'

Comment: Ok, i fix it buy changing return type to void. Thank you, its helpful to discuss.